# Interview Question, how to prevent n threads n resources deadlock in java

Tags: multithreading

This question was asked in an interview and the approach taken architecturally to solve this problem at high level was being judged. In Java, how can this be solved
-->N threads .. n resources .. what protocol do you use to ensure no deadlocks occur?

So, can someone let me know the most optimal approach ? making all the methods synchronized 
can make the system deadlocked, so how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Why are you worried about deadlock? Deadlock is only going to occur if thread A is has resource a locked and is waiting on resource b, and thread B has resource b locked and is waiting on resource a, or a similar scenario.

Comment: Is this just a generic question or do you have a particular problem? The generic answer would propably be to code it accordingly, draw a diagram or something and evaluate all possibilities.

Comment: Always acquire the resources in the same order :)

Comment: Please more detail. Which resources is every thread going to use? Only one, all of them, a subset?

Comment: @Nikolai: should be an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably they're looking for [lock ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951275/would-you-explain-lock-ordering). That is, if you use more than one lock and more than one thread, you *must* ensure that the locks are always obtained in the same order. Otherwise a deadlock is just a matter of time.

Answer (score 1):

N Threads can Access N Resources if there is no Sharing without any problem, The challenge Comes when there is a Resource Shared among different threads.

Lets us take example of Printer,Scanner,Oven,Coffee Machine In our office we consider them as Resources and Employees as Threads so what happens if 2 Resources say Employee John and Christen comes for Coffee they Stand in a Queue There is no Parallel processing by Coffee Machine, Same with Printer Employee Venkat submits a printing job at the same time Jame also submits printing job it goes to a Job Queue.

So you have to implement Blocking Queue and Resources as Consumers.

In case if you work with Semaphores , you can control no of threads entering to your critical section.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give some more details?

Having a counter protected by "synchronized" may be all that is required.

Comment: "synchronized" may also be all that is required for a deadlock to occur :-)